# React Native for Mac

Tags: macos, react-native

I'm using React Native to build a mobile App. 
Also I have a similar Mac App, I'm wondering if React Native can be adapted for Mac, how difficult it is.

Comment: See this [official issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/247).

Answer (score 14):

React Native - doesn't support native OS X app, it is geared towards mobile native applications.

Even though it doesn't seem to be easy to adapt the code to run as a native OS X app, there is at least one project that is attempting to do that (the author of the project states that this was a weekend hack project and therefore not production ready, but nonetheless a good start point):

https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-desktop

Comment: Why isn't it easy to adapt the code to run on desktop? Just curious.

Answer (score 6):

Check out React Native for macOS, it appears to be what you are looking for:  https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-macos

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13424127)

Comment: In this case, it seems to me that the answer *is* the link. The question asks for a way to use React Native to build a Mac app; the link points to a tool which accomplishes this.

Answer (score 4):

You may also consider [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), however this is not a React-specific solution.